# The method toggleKey(int, boolean) is undefined for the type InputHandler

Tags: java, input, key

I was wandering if anyone could help, basically im following a tuorial on some input handling and the tutorial reguires me to create a new class and write this code.

```
package net.pinkeye.JavaGame;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InputHandler implements KeyListener{

public InputHandler(Game game) {
    game.addKeyListener(this);
}

public class Key {
    public boolean pressed = false;

    public boolean isPressed(){
        return pressed;
    }
    public void toggle(boolean isPressed) {
        pressed = isPressed;
    }
}


public Key up = new Key();  
public Key down = new Key();    
public Key left = new Key();    
public Key right = new Key();

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(),true);
}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(),false);
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}


public void toggle (int keyCode, boolean isPressed) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        up.toggle(isPressed);
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        down.toggle(isPressed);
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A){
        left.toggle(isPressed);
    }   
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D){
        right.toggle(isPressed);
    }
}

}
```

however where it says

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(),true);
}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(),false);
}
```

eclipse tells me The method toggleKey(int, boolean) is undefined for the type InputHandler

ive followed this tutorial word for wrd and checked multiple times but i can't find my mistake.

Any help would be great

Btw here is thwe tuorial if this helps: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv7G5GMOre8

Comment: So let me get this straight -- you're calling a method `toggleKey(...)` that you've not declared anywhere, and you're surprised when it causes your code not to compile. I'm mainly surprised as to why you're surprised. What confuses you about this? Why not call  methods that you actually have in your class?

Comment: Yeah i know but this tutorial doesn't declare it??

Comment: Doesn't matter. Your code makes no logical sense. Don't blindly follow a tutorial -- use your brain and common sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your actual method is called `toggle` but you've declared the possibility of invoking `toggleKey`. Renaming `toggle` to `toggleKey` should solve your problem.

Comment: It should work. The error is so obvious and Derek is right. The 'toggle' method in your 'Key' class should be left alone as it is. But do rename the 'toggle' method with the signature 'public void toggle (int keyCode, boolean isPressed)' to 'public void toggleKey (int keyCode, boolean isPressed)'.

Comment: Yeah i just realised the guy typed out the toggle and later without a word renamed it t toggle key Thanks anyway

Comment: One of the worst questions of the day.

Comment: Don't get demotivated by the silly errors you make. Keep coding. Before you know you are a good programmer. Good luck!